# While loop decorator

Tags: python

I am using the `ftp` library which is incredibly finicky when downloading a bunch of files. This will error about once every 20 tries:

```
ftp.cwd(locale_dir)
```

So, what I do which fixes it is:

```
while True:
    try:
        ftp.cwd(locale_dir)
    except:
        continue
    break
```

How would I write a python decorator to do this, as I have to do the above on about 10 ftp commands in a script. It would be nice if I could have something like:

```
retry_on_failure(ftp.cwd(locale_dir))
```

Comment: Looks like [someone already did that](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying).

Comment: @tobias_k cool, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create decorator as:

```
def retry_on_failure(count=10): # <- default count as 10
    def retry_function(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            while count > 0:
                try:
                   func_response = function(view, request, *args, **kwargs)
                   break  # <- breaks the while loop if success 
                except:
                   count -= 1
                   func_response = None
            return func_response
        return wrapper
    return retry_function
```

Now create your file download function with this decorator as:

```
@retry_on_failure(count=20)  # <- will make attempts upto 20 times if unable to downlaod 
def download_file(file_name):
    ftp.cwd(file_namee)
```

You may use this decorator with any function, where you need to make a retry attempt in case of any exception (not just your file download function). This is the beauty of `decorators`, these are generic adoptable by any function ;)

In order to make a call to `download_file` fuction, just do:

```
download_file(file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I just do: `retry_on_failure(ftp.cwd(locale_dir))` instead of having to throw it in another function? In other words, pass it just as a function call instead of a decorator?

Comment: Updated the answer, check the last line

Comment: I see -- is there a way to pass a function name to the retry on failure? Otherwise, I have to create a separate function with a decorator for each changed function.

Comment: @David542 `retry_on_failure(ftp.cwd(locale_dir))` can't work, as this will execute the normal `ftp.cwd` before passing the result of that function to the decorator. I guess you could use `retry_on_failure(count=20)(ftp.cwd)(locale_dir)` though (same with the `retrying` package). But defining a decorated wrapper seems to be a lot cleaner than doing this each time you want to call the function.

Comment: @David542: As was told by tobias, `retry_on_failure(count=20)(ftp.cwd)(locale_dir)` will work but it is not the good practice to call the function with decorator, when you need to do the same thing at multiple places. It is better to create a separate function, with decorator over it, even if the function is of one line

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri when I try running this I get a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the syntax you want, because in that code `ftp.cwd(locale_dir)` gets called before `retry_on_failure`, so any exception it raises will prevent the `retry` function from running. You could separate the function and its arguments, however, and call something like `retry_on_failure(ftp.cwd, (locale_dir,))`.

Here's an implementation that would work with that syntax. (Note, this isn't a decorator, as that's usually meant in Python.)

```
def retry_on_failure(func, args=(), kwargs={}):
    while True:
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

This will of course run forever if the function *always* raises an exception, so use with care. You could add a limit to the number of repetitions or add logging if you wanted to.

Comment: OP has never mentioned that he wants a function. He told that he needs decorator. And it depends on the logic within the decorator that whether the function is to be executed before or after the logic within the decorator. It can definitely be handled

Comment: His desired use case was a function call, not a decorator. The specific syntax he used can't work, but something similar can. Creating a decorator just because that's the buzzword he mentioned is less helpful, I think, since it's not clear the questioner actually knows what a decorator is. I think he was just using it as a term for a higher-order function.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks, this is very straightforward and easy to use. How would I apply the above to something like: `ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % file, open(local_path, 'wb').write)` ?

Comment: It should work with `retry_on_failure(ftp.retrbinary, ('RETR %s' % file, open(local_path, 'wb').write))`. That is, bundle all the positional arguments into a tuple and pass them as the second argument to `retry_on_failure`. A slightly different approach would be to change the `retry_on_failure` function to use `*args` and `**kwargs` (instead of positional arguments by those names), and call `retry_on_failure(ftp.retrbinary, 'RETR %s' % file, open(local_path, 'wb').write)` (note the slightly different parentheses).

Comment: @Blckknght this is very helpful. Thank you very much.